# Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR: UNION types character varying and date cannot be matched

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hello hope y'all doing well. I am trying to union three different tables that have a unique parent with Laravel. Below is the code:

```html
$storage_rent = DB::table('storage_rents')
            ->select('order_id', 'start_date', 'end_of_free_charge', 'orders.order_type')
            ->distinct()
            ->join('orders', 'storage_rents.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
            ->where('start_date', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orWhere('end_of_free_charge', 'like', '%' . $q . '%');
        $car_parkings = DB::table('car_parkings')
            ->select('order_id', 'start_date', 'end_of_free_charge', 'orders.order_type')
            ->distinct()
            ->join('orders', 'car_parkings.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
            ->where('start_date', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orWhere('end_of_free_charge', 'like', '%' . $q . '%');
        return DB::table('shippings')
            ->select('order_id', 'port_of_destination', 'booking_number', 'orders.order_type')
            ->distinct()
            ->join('orders', 'shippings.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
            ->where('port_of_destination', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orWhere('container_number', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orWhere('booking_number', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->union($storage_rent)
            ->union($car_parkings)            
            ->get();
```

When I run that code, it works perfectly on Postman but if I deploy it on heroku postgresql, it gives me an error: SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  UNION types character varying and date cannot be matched. How can I resolve the issue, assuming that I wanted to query in each table. Result that it gives me on POSTMAN:

```html
[
    {
        "order_id": 9,
        "port_of_destination": "saint louis",
        "booking_number": "",
        "order_type": "Shipping"
    },
    {
        "order_id": 11,
        "port_of_destination": "2021-09-28",
        "booking_number": "2021-10-28",
        "order_type": "Storage rent"
    },
    {
        "order_id": 10,
        "port_of_destination": "2021-10-08",
        "booking_number": "2021-10-15",
        "order_type": "Car Parking"
    }
]
```

Comment: your servers have differnet options enables, so chekc them on both server i am guessing strict mode

Comment: thanks @nbk , i will check on the server.